# Merging/Dissolving features with same ID using Transformer in FME?

Tags: shapefile, transformer, fme-form

I was looking to merge some features to improve the performance of some of my layers on my ArcGIS Server. I have a few very large polyline layers for our fiber network that are exported out of a CAD based program (Mapcom M4) every week and into a GeoDatabase. I did notice that some of the features have the same attributes and fiber ID's, but are separated into up to between 4-15 different lines. When I tested this out and manually dissolved the featueres into one based on fiber ID it drastically improved performance. This would be a significant expense of time to do every week, though, and I was looking to make it part of my Weekly FME Workbench. I just wasn't sure what  transformer would make the most sense to use to merge all the features with the same Fiber ID before writing them to the Geodatabase.

Comment: FeatureMerger or Aggregator are the two I'd look at to start with.  Which transformers have you looked at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aggregator** will merge geometries based on a specified attribute.  If you aren't concerned with any other attributes you can tell it not to keep other attributes, otherwise it can concatenate/sum/average those too.

[image]

Comment: OK I am trying out Aggregator now. It looks like what I needed! thanks

Comment: Hmm, According to the workbench it seemed to work, but when looking at the actual tables it doesn't look like it did. I think I am using an older version, but does it look like I have the proper settings? I wanted to aggregate the ID's but keep the other attributes. https://i.imgur.com/6Fj8oQr.png https://i.imgur.com/xYKvJSB.png

Comment: do the attributes differ across the different features (of the same ID)?  You could possibly pull the attributes into your new dataset using a different transformer

Comment: Thank you! The Aggregator worked. I just had to set the Accumulate Attributes to "Yes" and Concatenate all the attributes besides ID. Thanks!